# OR operator between two foreign keys in sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have two foreign key at my table and i'm trying to use a OR operator to select only the table that have the param.
Is there a possible way to do this condition? Something like that:

```
    include: [
                {
                    model: Segurado,
                    as: "segurado",
                },
                where: {
                    [Op.or]: {
                        {
                            model: Produtor,
                            as: "produtor1",
                            where: {
                                codigo: id_produtor,
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            model: Produtor,
                            as: "produtor2",
                            where: {
                                codigo: id_produtor,
                            },
                        },
                    }
                }
            ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling the model inside the where clause. Like that:

```
 {
   where: {
       [Op.or]: [
           { '$produtor1.documento$': documento_produtor },
          { '$produtor2.documento$': documento_produtor }
       ]
     },
     include: [
    {
        model: Produtor,
        as: "produtor1"
    },
    {
        model: Produtor,
        as: "produtor2"
    }
  ]
}
```